# Failed dependencies: POSTGIS RHEL6

Tags: redhat, dependencies, postgis

I am attempting to install POSTGIS on RHEL6.3x64.
To do this I used the following steps

- installed epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
- yum install postgis

There was a dependency issue and would not install.

```
 Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
 Updating certificate-based repositories.
 Unable to read consumer identity
 Setting up Install Process
 Resolving Dependencies
   --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package postgis.x86_64 0:1.5.3-1.el6 will be installed
   --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
   --> Processing Dependency: proj for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
   --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: libproj.so.0()(64bit) for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64 
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package postgis.x86_64 0:1.5.3-1.el6 will be installed
  --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
  ---> Package proj.x86_64 0:4.7.0-1.rhel6 will be installed
  --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db for package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
  Error: Package: postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: /usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any ideas how I can complete the installation of postgis, can not seem to get past the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/usr/bin/rebuild-gcj-db` is in the `java-1.5.0-gcj` package, which is in the Red Hat system repositories.

The fact that you can't find it most likely means that your Red Hat subscription for this machine is not active. Give the machine a subscription entitlement and try again.

Alternately, convert the system to CentOS.

Comment: Thanks you for the fast response.  Activated the subscription and all set.

Comment: @Dave If the answer resolved your problem, remember to click the outline of the check mark next to it. This marks the question as resolved for the benefit of others, and also increases your reputation. Welcome to Server Fault!